# Handling data from incoming request - React.js/Next.js

Tags: next.js, backend

I have a problem. In Poland we have a payment system and I'm trying to integrate API with it.
When data is properly fetched I received a token, and redirecting to payment web site everything goes fine, but after successful payment this payment system sending me data via URL.

Problem is that I don't know how to get this data. A thought that I need to have some listening API endpoint but can't create this. Please help, I'm living link to docs below.
https://developers.przelewy24.pl/index.php?en

Fetch method and API endpoints

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by me and the hotline of this platform. Maybe someone will look for the answer. IMO Next.js is not able to retrieve the data in this way. I needed a backend that listens for the url with the POST method. Node.js (express) is good for such cases with a simple app.post() waiting for data from an external API / request and storing it in a variable.
The frontend can then retrieve the data from these variables